# Couldn't execute with maven version

Tags: maven, apt-get

I'm new to storm and maven i installed

```
Apache Maven 3.1.0
```

and need to use it to maven a project

when i used `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classPathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=MYClass.cr`

I got

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

except

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.0
```

Comment: Stop using such old version of Maven...First use the latest on the appropriate branch which means `3.1.1` instead of `3.1.0` and may be you should use a more up-to-date version..

Comment: i deleted it and install maven using apt-get install maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running `/usr/bin/mvn` (verify this by typing `which mvn`). This is where `apt-get` will install maven.  However, you have installed maven somewhere under `/opt`, so simply running `mvn` isn't finding the maven you installed.

First ensure that your .bashrc is updated to include the correct path, and that the new path is *before* `/usr/bin`

```
PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin:$PATH
```

Then you need to ensure that .bashrc is loaded. You can log out and in again, start a new console, or simply source it (`. ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: last question in this point , does sudo apt-get install maven will be convention with jdk6 ? and version of this maven will be 3 or what ?

Comment: The JDK is mostly irrelevant: it will use whichever one it finds, though probably only Java 5 and up (not sure). The `maven` apt is maven 3. The `maven2` apt is maven 2. maven 1 is no longer available through normal apt channels.